# UnionFS: How to persist changes in the overlay/upperdir into the base/lowerdir filesystem?

Tags: linux, ext4, unionfs

Suppose to have the following scenario, on a linux system:

- An ext4 data partition mounted as Read-Only: `data_ro`
- An overlay partition: `data_overlay`
- The two of them union-mounted using UnionFS: `mount -t overlayfs -o lowerdir=data_ro,upperdir=data_overlay overlayfs data`

At a certain point in time it is needed to persist the changes from `data_overlay` into `data_ro` (obviously `data_ro` will be remounted R/W in such case and then remounted back R/O).

---

How to persist changes in the overlay/upperdir into the base/lowerdir filesystem?

Is it coping/moving from overlay to the base FS enough, like in the following commands sequence?

```
umount data
mount -o remount,rw data_ro
mv -rf data_overlay data_ro
mount -o remount,ro data_ro
mount -t overlayfs -o lowerdir=data_ro,upperdir=data_overlay overlayfs data
```